AutoSAR : Multiple Freezeframe per event
AutoSAR : in multiple freezeframe why demDidIdentifier multiplicity is 1 w.r.t data element? How the configuration for multiple freezeframe diff dids are configured ?
I want to design autosar 4.4.0 multiple freezeframe  records per Events,So need to figure out how to configured number of different dids shall be assign in each records.
